# VBA "&" functionality on a range of cells

Tags: vba, excel

I know this may be a basic question, but being new with VBA, I am having trouble getting the syntax to work. I've searched alot of sites, but could only get it to work within part of the range, but not both. So if I wanted to merge cells Q, R, S, T on row 1, I could easily write:

```
Range("Q1:T1").Merge
```

However, As I am working within a loop, I'd like to have row numbers that alter. How could I fix the syntax on this? Y being the row count.

```
Range("Q"&y":T"&y).Merge
```

Comment: Range("Q" & y & ":T" & y).Merge

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 Range("Q" & y & ":T" & y).Merge
```

You missed a '&' between the first y and the quote.

Answer (score 4):

There are several options, including:

```
Range("Q" & y & ":T" & y).Merge
```

or

```
Range("Q" & y, "T" & y).Merge
```

or

```
Range("Q" & y).Resize(, 4).Merge
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is another way of writing it that I like but you never see examples of it:

`Rows(y).Columns("Q:T").Merge`

Comment: You would usually see that kind of method used with `Intersect()` which is probably why you don't see it often.

Comment: The pattern itself acts like intersect.  One draw back is that it's one more thing to explain.  The average user is used to seeing `Range(Cells(10,1),Cells(20,10))`  not  `Rows("10:20").Columns("A:J")`